# Getting null result although there is in database

Tags: mysql

Here, I am using mysql query as it shows null result or empty result although there are records in database.
So, where is the problem actually?

```
SELECT `fx_tasks`.*, `fx_assign_tasks`.`assigned_user` 
FROM (`fx_tasks`) 
LEFT JOIN `fx_assign_tasks` 
  ON `fx_assign_tasks`.`task_assigned` = `fx_tasks`.`t_id` 
WHERE `fx_tasks`.`project` = 55 
  AND str_to_date(`fx_tasks`.`start_date`, "%d-%m-%Y") 
      BETWEEN "08-09-2015" AND "28-09-2015" 
ORDER BY `fx_tasks`.`t_id` DESC
```

Comment: Always use SINGLE QUOTES `BETWEEN '08-09-2015' AND '28-09-2015'` and `str_to_date(\`fx_tasks\`.\`start_date\`, '%d-%m-%Y') `

Comment: @JorgeCampos: There is *no difference* between single and double quotes in MySQL.

Comment: @RocketHazmat well, that depends on the mysql configuration (ANSI_QUOTES sql mode is set, then double quotes are interpreted as identifiers, not as string delimiters).

Comment: @RocketHazmat you are right. MySQL doesn't quite follow the SQL ANSI pattern, at least not all of then. See this [sql ansi docs](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) section 4.2.4 Named character sets. Same as the weird group by without all fields on the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in MySQL need to be in the `Y-m-d` format.

```
str_to_date(`fx_tasks`.`start_date`, "%d-%m-%Y") 
    BETWEEN "2015-09-08" AND "2019-09-28"
```

From the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

When you use `str_to_date`, it uses the format string to *parse* the value from the db and then returns you a `DATE` value - in `Y-m-d` format.

P.S. If `fx_tasks.start_date` is *already* a `DATE` type, then you don't need `str_to_date`.

P.P.S. If you want to print a `DATE` in a different format, use [`date_format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Thanks Rocket.. but what about if there are records for date like, "08-09-2015"...?

Comment: Thanks Rocket.. but what about if there are records for date like, "08-09-2015"...?

Comment: then you need to convert your varchar records into actual date/time fields and properly format them. you should never be storing dates as string-types. strings are essentially useless for date math, and that's what you need to be doing - date math.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with the `str_to_date(fx_tasks.start_date, "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN "08-09-2015" AND "28-09-2015"`  part (not with the double quotes, though). The `start_date` is converted to date, which is in YYYY-MM-DD format in mysql, and then you compare it to a string containing a date in a different format. No records would satisfy this criterion.

Change the dates in the above criterion to YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
str_to_date(`fx_tasks`.`start_date`, "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN "2015-09-08" AND "2019-09-28"
```